# Onde devo colocar a FK?

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

Estou a aprender sobre base de dados, quando uma dúvida surgiu.

Por exemplo, tenho duas tabelas:

**usuario** `(_iduser, nome, sexo, ect.._)`

**login** `(_idlogin, login, senha_))`

Tem relacionamento `1:1`. Minha dúvida é justamente se eu posso colocar a FK em qualquer uma das duas tabelas, ou se há uma regra quanto isto que devo seguir.

Answer (score 2):

Antes de mais, em relacionamentos de 1:1 eu coloco tudo numa só tabela.

De qualquer forma se quiseres separar as tabelas, aqui está uma solução:

tabela **usuario**

```
iduser (PK)
nome
sexo
```

tabela **login**

```
iduser (PF) 
login
senha
```

Nota: aqui o campo `iduser` é uma Primary/Foreign Key, ou seja, é ao mesmo tempo uma chave primária e uma chave estrangeira

Uma das razões porque não gosto de ter duas tabelas em relacionamentos de 1:1 é o facto de haver necessidade de fazer primeiro um INSERT na tabela `usuario`, sacar o `iduser` que foi gerado e só depois posso fazer o INSERT na tabela `login`.

Answer (score 2):

O Codigo ficaria mais o menos assim:

```
Create Table Tb_Usuario
(
Id_Usuario Int Not Null Identity Primary Key,
Nome varchar(20) Not Null Unique,
Sexo bit Not Null
)

Create Table Tb_Login
(
Id_Login Int Not Null Identity Primary Key,
Id_Usuario Int Not Null References Tb_Usuario(Id_Usuario),
Pass varchar(10) Not Null
)
```

Não sei correctamente para que queres mais isto é um basico

Comment: Isso não responde à pergunta do OP.

Answer (score 0):

Concordo com o que o Sandro disse, para essa sua situação em particular. É interessante você sempre analisar o cenário que você esta desenvolvendo. Por exemplo, no seu caso é interessante fazer o relacionamento 1:1 na mesma tabela, pois são poucas informações, mas vamos imaginar um cenário diferente:

Você esta desenvolvendo por exemplo uma aplicação de aluguel de veiculos, então você tem uma tabela Aluguel por exemplo:

```
(Tabela - Aluguel)
id(PK)
idCarro(FK) ManyToOne
idMotorista(FK) ManyToOne
dataDevolucao
dataEntrega
dataPedido
valorTotal
```

E para cada Aluguel você precisa de uma Apolice de Seguro:

```
(Tabela - ApoliceSeguro)
id(PK)
protecaoCausasNaturais
protecaoRoubo
protecaoTerceiro
valorFranquia
```

Reparou como o cenário mudou, se você colocar na mesma tabela o relacionamento 1:1, sua tabela vai ficar com muitas informações que não é dela. O seguro, pertence a aluguel, mas tem as informações sobre seguro, então é uma separação de responsabilidades.

Então para esse cenário específico na tabela Aluguel, você terá uma FK da seguinte maneira:

```
idApoliceSeguro(FK) OneToOne
```

Sobre a necessidade de realizar mais de um INSERT. Alguns framework podem te auxiliar nessa tarefa, como o Hibernate. Vamos imaginar que você tente realizar apenas (1) INSERT. Vai ocorrer o erro dizendo que o objeto esta referenciando uma instancia não salva, salve primeiro esta intancia não salva antes de descarregar os dados no banco de dados. A instancia que ele esta se referindo é a ApoliceSeguro.

Caso esteja utilizando o Hibernate por exemplo, você poderia criar um DAO da apolice de serguro, salvar ela antes, assim ela passa a ser um objeto persistido e gerenciado pelo EntityManager e ele vai ter o código para conseguir salvar o Aluguel.

Ou então, na anotação @OneToOne, você utiliza a propriedade (cascade=CascadeType.ALL) para todas as operações ou somente para determinadas operações como PERSIST, MERGE e etc.

Mas no seu caso em específico, tenho uma sugestão, separe as responsabilidades e use um relacionamento (ManyToMany), eu faria da seguinte forma:

```
(TABELA - usuario)
id(PK)
nome
senha

(TABELA - grupo)
id(FK)
descricao
nome

(TABELA - usuario_grupo)
id_usuario(FK)
id_grupo(FK)
```

Dessa maneira eu posso gerenciar da seguinte forma:

- GRUPO = Administrador, Gerente, Funcionario, ...
- Usuario = usuario (X) pertence ao grupo Administrador
- Usuario = usuario (y) pertence ao grupo Gerente

E assim por diante...

Dessa maneira você gerencia na sua aplicação os direitos que cada grupo tem e quais usuários vão receber esses direitos.